# how to fix error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context near Horse d = new Horse ();

Tags: java, inheritance

Im getting this error that non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context:  `Horse d = new Horse ();`

```
public class Animal {
    public void sound() {
        System.out.println("sounds");
    }

    class Horse extends Animal {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("neigh");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Horse d = new Horse();
        d.run();
        d.sound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution :

1. declare your class outside the `Animal` class
2. or declare your class as static `static class Horse extends Animal {..}`

Comment: Third option: create an instance of `Animal`: `new Animal().new Horse()` would work (I believe), but seems unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Horse` class is an inner class of the `Animal` class, which means it requires an enclosing `Animal` instance in order to be instantiated.

This makes no sense. Simply move the `Horse` class outside the `Animal` class.

```
public class Animal 
{  
    public void sound()
    {
        System.out.println("sounds");
    }
}

public class Horse extends Animal
{
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("neigh");
    }
}
```

It's up to you where to put the `main` method, but it makes less sense for the base `Animal` class to be aware of its `Horse` sub-class, so I wouldn't create a `Horse` instance inside the `Animal` class's code.